# label value overlapping due to overcrowd in pie chart

Tags: swift, pie-chart

I am working on pie chart. Text values of pie chart are overlapping due to multiple data as shown in figure below. I am not getting how to separate out these data with no overlapping labels.
[image: here is my screeShot]

My code is

```
         pieChartDataSet.colors = colors
        pieChartDataSet.valueFormatter = ChartValueFormatter()

        pieChartDataSet.valueLinePart1Length = 0.7
        pieChartDataSet.valueLinePart2Length = 0.3
        //pieChartDataSet.valueLinePart1OffsetPercentage = 80.0
        pieChartDataSet.valueLineColor = .black;
        pieChartDataSet.valueTextColor = .black;
        pieChartDataSet.valueFont = UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 8.0)!
        pieChartDataSet.valueLineVariableLength = true
        pieChartDataSet.yValuePosition = .outsideSlice;
        pieChartDataSet.xValuePosition = .outsideSlice;
```

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: I have used another library to avoid this.

Comment: Can i get that link for this used lib ?@Nitu